# Change increment customer ID from 1 to 00001 with zero padding

Tags: database, customer, magento-1, export, eav

Is there a way to change the customer ID to start with 00001. Now it's just 1. I need this for importing into a different system.

So each customer number starting with 00001, 00002 and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly advise *against* altering core tables or their auto increment. Instead translate it when retrieved for export/import using str_pad or sprintf i.e.:

`$id = 1;
$exportId = str_pad($id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` -> 
[3v4l example](http://3v4l.org/X9ifv)

OR

`$id = 1;
$exportId = sprintf('%05d',$id);` -> [3v4l example](http://3v4l.org/A8dpu)

Answer (score 4):

To use increment ids for customers (the same way as for orders), you have to enable them first, via configuration:

*Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID*

Afterwards you can change padding size in the `eav_entity_store` (there is no admin interface for it, you have to do it directly in the database. The `entity_type_id` for customers is `1`.

(Note that this is not related to the MySQL auto increment id and you are *not altering* core tables)

Comment: My latest customer ID at the moment is 10. I want my next customer to have the ID '45630'. and the for every customer it should increment this id. I've set this in eav_entity_store for last_increment_id but no luck.

Comment: Still I am not getting the use of `Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID` . Could you please elaborate? @Fabian

Comment: @KeyurShah if you enable this, the `increment_id` column is used for customer numbers, instead of the `entity_id` column. If not, `increment_id` is not populated.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I enabled it still I can not see any effect on new customer created Id. am I missing something ? @FabianSchmengler

Comment: Where do you look for an effect?

Answer (score -2):

**Order, credit, invoice and shipping ID:**

In your store database go to **eav_entity_store** and change the values of **increment_last_id**, you can change all the number types (order,credit,invoice,shipping).

This is a great source for more in-depth information about this: [Link](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/)

**Customer ID:**

The customer ID increment can be altered from the **customer_entity** table.
Or by this SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 00001;
```

Comment: but I want to achieve for every customer ID starting with 00001, 00002, 00003. eav_entity_store and increment_last_id looks like order ID not customer ID.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, I just updated the post. Hope it helps.

Comment: so when i run this query it will change all customers id to 00001, 00002 and so on ?

Comment: Getting error: ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT =0001

MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'electroweld.customer_entity' doesn't exist

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Modify the data outside of Magento's DB or build a separate table to do the translation. Messing with the EAV system is going to land you in a world of hurt; especially if you don't document the fact that you have to run manual SQL queries to get a fresh install to this state. If you're simply doing this for an import into another system then build it out in your import/export process.

Comment: p.s. you can just use str_pad or sprintf to achieve your desired result.